# SymPyで作成したグラフの一部描画について

Tags: python, sympy

SymPyで作成した数式のグラフについて質問致します。

以下のサンプルコードを例にしますと、座標平面上の第一象限に一次関数と円のグラ
フが計三つ作成されます。

これらのグラフにより分割される各領域に関しまして、例えば三つのグラフの＆を取
る領域等、特定の領域のみを描画することは可能でしょうか。
もしお分かりでしたら、ご助言よろしくお願い致します。

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols("x y")

I = (x - 30)**2 + (y - 30)**2 -400
J = y + 2*x -60
K = (x - 10)**2 + (y - 20)**2 -200

p1 = plot_implicit(I, (x, 0,100), (y, 0,100), show=False, line_color='b')
p2 = plot_implicit(J, (x, 0,100), (y, 0,100), show=False, line_color='b')
p3 = plot_implicit(K, (x, 0,100), (y, 0,100), show=False, line_color='b')

p1.extend(p2)
p1.extend(p3)
p1.show()
```

Comment: 頂点というのはこの場合、交点の事かと思いますので、例えば `solve([I, J], [x, y])` とすれば良いかと。

Comment: 少し説明が足りず申し訳ございません。最終的な目的は複数の関数の交点で囲まれた領域を描画することなのですが、サンプルでは一次関数ですがそれ以外の複雑な関数ですと、領域の境界が直線ではなくなるためどのようにすべきか分かりませんでした。

Comment: 若干質問内容を修正致しました。

Answer (score 0):

SymPyの`plot_implicit`は、第1引数に不等式を与えると、その不等式が満たされる領域を塗りつぶします。今の場合、`(I < 0) & (J < 0) & (K < 0)`のようにして、領域のANDを指定することができます（Pythonの演算子は、`<`よりも`&`の方が優先されるので、括弧が必要）。

```py
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols("x y")

I = (x - 30) ** 2 + (y - 30) ** 2 - 400
J = y + 2 * x -60
K = (x - 10) ** 2 + (y - 20) ** 2 - 200

p1 = plot_implicit(I, (x, 0, 100), (y, 0, 100), show=False, line_color="b")
p2 = plot_implicit(J, (x, 0, 100), (y, 0, 100), show=False, line_color="b")
p3 = plot_implicit(K, (x, 0, 100), (y, 0, 100), show=False, line_color="b")
p4 = plot_implicit((I < 0) & (J < 0) & (K < 0), (x, 0,100), (y, 0,100), show=False, line_color="r")

p1.extend(p2)
p1.extend(p3)
p1.extend(p4)
p1.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]